# Auto Resizing images to fit to browser (css Html)

Tags: html, css

Im having a problm getting my page to resize and scale correctly. Basicaly, the site will be opened in browsers, and tablets, on mobiles occasionaly. heres a snippet of the code :

```
<style type="text/css">
div#container
{
position:relative;
width: 1439px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
text-align:left; 
}
body {text-align:center;margin:0}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="g_image1" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden;
left:0px;  top:8px; width:1318px; height:88px; 
z-index:0"><img src="images/LogoHeader.jpg" alt="" title="" border=0 
width=1318 height=88></div>

<div id="image2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:81px;
top:100px; width:1317px; height:572px; z-index:1"><img 
src="images/TitlePicAerialSurveys.jpg" alt="" title="" border=0 
width=1317 height=572></div>
```

for example, image2 wont auto resize to the window size. is there a way to change the code to affect all images or should i do each image at a time with a auto resize code?

Comment: try to change your `width` into `width:100%` or search for @media

Comment: what's wrong with pasting your code right into the question? images don't make it easier to read.

Comment: Can you post the code in your question please? Thanks :-)

Comment: If i set the Width to 50% or even 100%, if i resize the page nothing scaled down. Ive tried adding the 50% and 100% to the divcontainer and also ive tried changing Image2's width and eight to %'s respectivley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height and width can be set to auto (this is default. Means that the browser calculates the height and width), or be specified in length values, like px, cm, etc., or in percent (%) of the containing block.

In your case **percent (%)** will do the job. You can also use media queries for better structuring of your page on different devices.

Answer (score 1):

You must manually add size for each of your window size (window, tablet, mobile). This current image behaviour is normal.

Add a specific image size in css for each @media.

My example :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) { 
  .imgClassResize { 
     width : yoursize
   } 
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) { 
  .imgClassResize { 
     width : yoursize
   } 
}
```

Comment: You don't have to do it manually.. That will be hard-coded and each image has different sizes. So procents will be the best solution for this, the browser will automatic stretch the images when the `%` is set.

Comment: I didn't mean to resize EACH image, but every images in several media.

My example :

     @media screen and (max-width: 1280px) { .imgClassResize { width : yoursize} }

Comment: Than edit it in your answer. You can say something like: `Add different screensizes with the @media query` and give your answer an example for it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not try jQuery

suppose for the image

```
<img id="img" src="images/image.jpg">
```

use the below code to set the width to 100%

```
var w = innerWidth;
$('#img').css({"width":w});
```

if you don't want to use js, then you will need to set the width in percentage

```
#img{
    width:100%;
}
```